# Extension for Safari to enable Google Translation WITHOUT adding a button?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

In the safari extensions there is a cool extension to use google translate on the current web page: "Translate".

However I don't like the fact it is adding a button to the bar. I would like to make it work as in Chrome, where the bar automatically appears when a website is in a foreign language.

thanks

Comment: If memory serves, that is an option in the extension settings. Have you checked there?

Comment: I haven't seen any other option: http://cl.ly/7vWb

Comment: I see we are talking about different extensions. This is the one I am talking about and it has the option to load automatically (when viewing a website in a foreign language). http://chrisgordon.ca/plug-ins/53-safari/87-google-translate-bar.html

Comment: Ok I've added the extension and I've selected the "Load automatically" option: http://cl.ly/7vgC  However if I go to a website with a foreign language (not english), nothing happens. I've safari 5.0.5

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I have no other suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Franker](http://safariextensions.org/detail/Franker/). Translate only what i want (selected text or whole page), inject translated text into the page, no button (right click menu).

Comment: Seems not to be available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extension called Translate, you can download it here:
http://sidetree.com/extensions.html
(second from the bottom)

Comment: Isn't that what @Patrick is referring to in his first sentence?

Comment: @Dori It is.

Comment: There's now also an option to add a "Translate this Page" context menu item, so you can remove the toolbar item.

Comment: i have just tried Translate and it looks promising. But somehow it cannot translate anything (page is unchanged), or safari said `Sorry, this page can not be translated. Extensions can not access local pages.` Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Not possible to install anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the toolbar button off the menu bar and still get the context menu to translate a page. This is how I use it (I also use Franker for some inline translations)

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a custom search like `http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=auto&u={query}` to Alfred, or [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Safari" to URL of document 1
do shell script "open 'http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=auto&u='$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape ARGV[0]' " & quoted form of result & ")"
```